# Vertical alignment in textbox in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, alignment

1. In MS Word 2007 I drew a textbox and entered some text.
2. Then I right clicked on textbox and went to format shape
3. Then went to TextBox tab and reduced the top internal margin to 0.1 cm. , but still it seems there is too much space at the top inside the textbox.
4. I am not able to position the text exactly at the vertical middle of textbox. If I choose the auto-rezide option in format Shape, the textBox size is increases automatically but the text remains exactly at vertical and horizontal middle of textbox. but anyhow I need the textbox to be small.

This is very minor but annoying problem.

Comment: move to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the paragraph formatting of the text to make sure it is not putting a space above or below the paragraph (just check in the usual Paragraph group on the Page Layout ribbon)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what just happened - cause I've been trying to fix it for ages. 
But I highlighted the top line (with the space above it), right clicked, went to 'paragraph' and selected 'Set as Default'.
And it all went right.
Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

> reduced the top internal margin to 0.1
>   cm

To get the tightest fitting box-to-text ratio:

- the text should have centred horizontal alignment
- In the textbox properties choose centred vertical alignment
- In the textbox properties reduce all the margins to zero
- In the textbox properties unset the *Resize Autoshape to Fit Text* property

That last point is the crucial one: automatic resizing enforce certain rules of good layout.  Unsetting it allows us to manual override those rules, and so shrink the box to whatever size pleases us.

[image: An image of a tight-fitting Textbox]

Comment: yes... I tried that one also.... still not working

Answer (score 0):

First you need to horizontalyl center the text from Home Tab. Hope this is already done.
To vertically center, right click on the outer margin of the textbox, select 'Format Text Box'. Go to 'Text box' tab, there you can do the vertical alignment. Hope this helps